# Finding a website's periodically changing URL via python

Tags: python, web

Let's say we have a website: [www.123example.com](http://www.123example.com)

The number inside the URL changes numerically upwards from time to time. (123 to 124, 124 to 125, maybe sometimes even much more 125 to 217 etc) I'd like to write a python code that scans and finds what the URL is that works, automatically instead of trying it manually.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the “requests” library to get a response from the website, including the status code which indicates whether the website is responding (200 means that it’s working).
Use a for loop to check the options.

Comment: Does the "requests" library do a HEAD request (which would be more efficient) or a full GET request?

Comment: full GET request